# GNUPLOT : Is it possible to generate plots in a loop?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a `.dat` file which looks like this

```
1 1.1
2 1.2
3 1.7
4 0.8
5 0.6
1 1.6
2 0.6
3 0.8
...
...
```

Where the first column will cycle `1 to 5`, which are the labels and second column will have the data I want to plot.

I want to plot different `plot.png` file for every `1 to 5` cycle.

Say for first `1 to 5`, the following script will run and save the `png` file to some name like `plot1.png`

Next `1 to 5` will be saved to `plot2.png`

Or the `.dat` file could be this

```
1 1.1
2 1.2
3 1.7
4 0.8
5 0.6
"plot_xyz"
1 1.6
2 0.6
3 0.8
...
...
"plot_zab"
```

each cycle following a file name to save to.

This is how I'm doing it for one set

```
reset session

set terminal pngcairo enhanced font "Bebas Neue,25" size 1920,1080
set output 'plot.png'

$DATA << EOD
1 0.7 
2 0.6 
3 0.5 
4 0.3 
5 0.9 
EOD

stats $DATA nooutput

N = STATS_columns
M = STATS_records

set angles degrees
do for [i=0:M-1] {
    stats $DATA every ::i::i using (labelValue=$1) nooutput

    if(labelValue==1){
        set label sprintf("Cr") at \
     posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
    }
    if(labelValue==2){
        set label sprintf("St") at \
     posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
    }
    if(labelValue==3){
        set label sprintf("Bu") at \
     posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
    }
    if(labelValue==4){
        set label sprintf("To") at \
     posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
    }
    if(labelValue==5){
        set label sprintf("Pr") at \
     posX(i,maxR),posY(i,maxR) center offset char posX(i,1),char posY(i,1)
    }
}
do for [j=1:numOfStepsInR] {
    set label sprintf("%.1f", j*deltaR) at 0,j*deltaR left offset char 0.5,0 tc rgb '#333333'
}

set parametric
set tr [0:1]

set xr [-1.1*maxR:1.1*maxR]
set yr [-1.1*maxR:1.1*maxR]

plot \
     for [i=0:M-1] \
     (cos(alpha(i))*(deltaR*(1-t)+t*maxR)),(sin(alpha(i))*(deltaR*(1-t)+t*maxR)) w l ls 42, \
     for [i=0:M-1] for [j=1:numOfStepsInR] \
     (j*deltaR*cos(alpha(i))*t + (1-t)*j*deltaR*cos(alpha(i+1))),(j*deltaR*sin(alpha(i))*t + (1-t)*j*deltaR*sin(alpha(i+1))) w l ls 42, \
     for [i=2:N] $DATA u (posX($0, column(i))):(posY($0, column(i))) w filledcurves closed fc rgb lcolor(i-2) fs border lc rgb lcolor(i-2) lw 2, \
     for [i=2:N] $DATA u (posX($0, column(i))):(posY($0, column(i))) w p ps 1.2 pt 7 lc rgb lcolor(i-2)
```

Would it be possible to loop generating plots from the `.dat` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a strict cycle (e.g. 5) you can use `every` as @jpeg pointed out.
Put the whole plotting in a `do for` loop and set the output file accordingly. Something like this (simplified).

```
reset session
set terminal pngcairo 

$DATA << EOD
1 1.1
2 1.2
3 1.7
4 0.8
5 0.6
1 1.6
2 0.6
3 0.8
4 0.8
5 0.6
EOD

stats $DATA nooutput
set parametric

N = STATS_columns
M = STATS_records
C = 5 # Cycle

do for [k=0:floor(M/C)-1] {
    set output sprintf("plot%d.png",k)
    plot \
        for [i=0:M-1] cos(i*t),sin(t),\
        for [i=2:N] $DATA u 1:2 every ::k*C::(k+1)*C-1 w p ps 1.2 pt 7 lc i
}
set output
```

Comment: It's work perfectly for the first graph, but for the next block I get error `stats command not available in parametric mode` when using `set parametric`. I've updated the post to give a better look.

Comment: simply put the `set parametric` command after the `stats` command and do a `reset session` at the beginning.

Comment: if you need `stats` in the loop just use `unset parametric` directly before `stats` and `set parametric` directly after.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong since there's isn't a `stats` command after `set parametric` in my file above. Although removing the loop does fixes it.

Comment: or the other way `set parametric` only directly before the `plot` command and `unset parametric` directly after.

Comment: Ah! That was it. Thank you!

Comment: If you wouldn't mind, can I ask how should I load a `nodes.dat` file directly into `$DATA` instead of using `$DATA << EOD .. points .. EOD`?

Comment: for example at the beginning enter a line `FILE = 'nodes.dat'`, skip the `$DATA ... EOD`-part and in the lines below replace `$DATA` by `FILE`.

Answer (score 1):

Leave a blank line between the data block belonging to each plot in your `.dat` file and use the `every` keyword to select a data block (see the `gnuplot` [Documentation](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/documentation.html) on page 92).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! So to select every block, I'd have to do `every ::x::x`. I assume I'll have to wrap it into a `for` loop. Although I'm not sure how I'd assign that block to `$DATA`

Comment: You can select the `i`th data block in your `for` loop using `every ::i::i` to generate the `i`th plot. Also be careful, I think you should use two different variable names for your two `for` loops (you have used `i` in both).